# Fine tunned Whisper-medium always predict "" for all samples

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model, openai-whisper, automatic-speech-recognition

i'm trying to fine tunning whisper-medium for Koreans language.

Here is [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper) that i followed.

And here is my experiment setting

```
python==3.9.16
transformers==4.27.4
tokenizers==0.13.3
torch==2.0.0
torchaudio==2.0.0
torchmetrics==0.11.4
torchvision==0.15.0
```

Here is preprocessing code for data

```
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import WhisperTokenizer
from datasets import Audio

def prepare_dataset(batch, tokenizer, feature_extractor):
    # load and resample audio data from 48 to 16kHz
    audio = batch["audio"]

    # compute log-Mel input features from input audio array 
    batch["input_features"] = feature_extractor(audio["array"], sampling_rate=audio["sampling_rate"]).input_features[0]

    # encode target text to label ids 
    batch["labels"] = tokenizer(batch["text"]).input_ids
    return batch

def main():
    dataset = load_dataset("Bingsu/zeroth-korean")
    dataset = dataset.cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=16000))
    feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-medium")
    tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-medium", language="ko", task="transcribe")

    mapped_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: prepare_dataset(x, tokenizer, feature_extractor), remove_columns=dataset.column_names["train"], num_proc=16)
    mapped_dataset.save_to_disk('./data/Bingsu_zeroth-korean', num_proc=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is training code.

```
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments
from datasets import load_from_disk
from utils import compute_metrics, DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding
import os
import argparse
import evaluate
def define_argparser():
    """Function to define the command line arguments
    
    Returns:
        argparse.Namespace: Command line arguments
    """
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--data_path', type=str, default='./data/Bingsu_zeroth-korean/')
    p.add_argument('--model_address', type=str, default='openai/whisper-medium')
    p.add_argument('--model_save_path', type=str, default='./models_zoo/openai_whisper-medium/')
    p.add_argument('--gradient_accumulation_steps', type=int, default=1)
    p.add_argument('--batch_size_per_device', type=int, default=24)
    # p.add_argument('--n_epochs', type=int, default=5)
    p.add_argument('--total_step', type=int, default=500)
    p.add_argument('--warmup_ratio', type=float, default=.2)
    # p.add_argument('--max_length', type=int, default=225)
    config = p.parse_args()

    return config

def main(config):
    """Main function to train the language model

    Args:
        config (argparse.Namespace): Command line arguments
    """
    dataset = load_from_disk(config.data_path)
    
    processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained(config.model_address, language="ko", task="transcribe")
    data_collator = DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding(processor=processor)
    model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(config.model_address)
    model.config.forced_decoder_ids = None
    model.config.suppress_tokens = []
    metric = evaluate.load("wer")
    
    print(
        '|train| =', len(dataset['train']),
        '|valid| =', len(dataset['test']),
    )
    
    # total_batch_size = config.batch_size_per_device * torch.cuda.device_count()
    # n_total_iterations = int(len(dataset['train']) / total_batch_size * config.n_epochs)
    n_total_iterations = config.total_step
    n_warmup_steps = int(n_total_iterations * config.warmup_ratio)
    
    print(
        '#total_iters =', n_total_iterations,
        '#warmup_iters =', n_warmup_steps,
    )
    training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
        output_dir=os.path.join(config.model_save_path, 'checkpoints'),
        # num_train_epochs=config.n_epochs,
        max_steps=n_total_iterations,
        per_device_train_batch_size=config.batch_size_per_device,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=config.batch_size_per_device,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=config.gradient_accumulation_steps,
        warmup_steps=n_warmup_steps,
        fp16=True,
        learning_rate=5e-6,
        gradient_checkpointing=True,
        evaluation_strategy='steps',
        save_strategy ='steps',
        report_to=["tensorboard"],
        logging_steps=25,
        save_steps=n_total_iterations // 5,
        eval_steps=n_total_iterations // 5,
        predict_with_generate=True,
        generation_max_length=config.max_length,
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        metric_for_best_model="wer",
        greater_is_better=False,
        dataloader_num_workers=16
    )
    trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
        args=training_args,
        model=model,
        train_dataset=dataset["train"],
        eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=lambda x: compute_metrics(x, metric, processor.tokenizer),
        tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor,
    )
    trainer.train()
    
    trainer.model.save_pretrained(os.path.join(config.model_save_path, 'model_weights'))
    # tokenizer.save_pretrained(os.path.join(config.model_save_path, 'tokenizer'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = define_argparser()
    main(config)
```

During the training, the training loss and evaluation loss goes down, but The WER goes 100.

And, after training, the model always predict <|startoftranscript|><|endoftext|> for all samples.

How should i fix this?

Comment: Add below code for model config, it works to me


`model.config.forced_decoder_ids=processor.get_decoder_prompt_ids()
model.config.suppress_tokens = []`